# GBR and FEN printout

Tags: chessboard, skak

How can I print the `GBR-code` and the `FEN` of the current position of `\chessboard` into the document?

Is this possible for instance for `FEN` without the transfer from `\chessboard` to `\chessgame` with the help of the keys `storefen` and `restorefen` and the following command `\boardasfen` from the `skak` package?

Up to now I don't know any command to output the `GBR-code` within the existing chess packages for LaTeX.

Any help would be kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print the FEN with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}
\chessboard[setpieces={Ke1,ke8,Ra1},storefen=myfen]

FEN: \csname chessgame.myfen\endcsname

\end{document}
```

There is no code/command to print the GBR but it is probably possible to build it with the help of the key getpiecelists.